# ¿Como puedo encontrar las tablas que causarian un error de integridad?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema que me da curiosidad, ya que no pude encontrar una respuesta buscando:

Tengo unas tablas que se asemejan al siguiente esquema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongamos que la tabla A tiene registros con el id 1 y yo quiero ejecutar el siguiente sql

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE id_A=1;
```

Pero el `id_A=1` existe en las tablas B, C y D, entonces recibiría este error:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (test.A, CONSTRAINT fk_A_B FOREIGN KEY (id_A)
>   REFERENCES A (id_A) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Lo cual tiene sentido ya que la FK me causa un error de integridad referencial. Ahora mi pregunta es esta ¿Hay una manera de saber si la FK va a impedirme borrar registros antes de que salga el error? Y si la hay ¿Existe manera de saber en cuantas y cuales tablas ocasionarian el error? Ya que el mysql solo me advierte de una y podrian haber varias.

Comment: aqui hay algunas pistas https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102374/152074

Comment: bueno, creo que eso debes acobijar todos loe escenarios posibles desde tu codigo ya que presisamente las **CONTRAINT** son la ultima capa de seguridad a la violacion de datos, por ende debes asegurarte de que ello nunca suceda atraves de los procesos de valiadacion necesario, en el caso de que necesite borrar alguna llave primaria deberias modificar la **CONTRAINT**  `ONDELTE CASCADE` o `ONUPDATE CASCADE`para que te permita eliminar

Comment: Hola, la solución se encuentra en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/how-to-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular-table-co Lo utilice varias veces, es útil cuando el modelo de datos esta muy desordenado.

Comment: A ver.. si eres el diseñador de la base seguro lo sabes, si no lo eres, imagino que hay forma de conocer las relaciones de una `FK` cualquiera, entonces simplemente deberías validar en todas estas tablas si existe determinado `ID`, ¿la pregunta que yo me haría, es vale la pena? Es la pregunta clásica: ¿Pedimos permiso o pedimos perdón?

Comment: Bueno basicamente se trata de un abm en el cual el usuario borra un registro, el abm ejecuta el delete y vuelve con el error. Entonces el usuario no sabe de donde sale el error y a cuantos lugares tiene que ir para deshacerse de ese registro. Basicamente me preguntaba si no existia un proceso que tenga el mysql para hacer lo que hace este SP https://pastebin.com/Ki2ie0vN ( que escribi al no tener una solucion mas sencilla )